# Martingale in Cox Model

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, martingales

Can someone help me to show that
$$
\hat{A}(t, \beta_0) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_0^t\frac{1}{\sum_{j}^n Y_j(s) e^{X_i^T \beta_0}} dN_i(s)
$$
is a martingale. The setup is the Cox proportional hazard model in a semiparametric manner.

This is what I got so far:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_0^t\frac{1}{\sum_{j}^n Y_j(s) e^{X_i^T \beta_0}} dN_i(s) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_0^t\frac{1}{\sum_{j}^n Y_j(s) e^{X_i^T \beta_0}} (dM_i(s|X) + d\Lambda_i(s|X) )
$$
$$
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_0^t\frac{1}{\sum_{j}^n Y_j(s) e^{X_i^T \beta_0}} (dM_i(s|X) + d \int_0^s Y_i(u) \alpha_0 e^{X_i^T \beta_0} du   )
$$
$$
=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_0^t\frac{1}{\sum_{j}^n Y_j(s) e^{X_i^T \beta_0}} dM_i(s|X) + \int_0^t\frac{1}{\sum_{j}^n Y_j(s) e^{X_i^T \beta_0}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i(s) e^{X_i^T \beta} \alpha_0(s)ds
$$
$$
=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_0^t\frac{1}{\sum_{j}^n Y_j(s) e^{X_i^T \beta_0}} dM_i(s|X) + \int_0^t \alpha_0(s)ds
$$